# how do I dynamically load an image into crystal reports designer?

Tags: crystal-reports

I am using crystal reports 2011 to create a .rpt report file. I use the designer window to layout the header page which has an image and some text. Is there a way to dynamically load the image from my hard drive?

For instance if I name the image logo.jpg and each time I run the report it would look for c:\logo.jpg on my hard drive and if the logo changes, it would automatically load the newest one?

Right now, I just copy and paste it into place. So I don't know where I would put the code to load it.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

- Add an image to the report and select any image on your computer.
- Now right click on the picture and go in format graphic.
- Click on the picture tab.
- Click the formula button with "picture location."
- Give the path to the picture you want loaded.